# jQuery show() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why this .show() method not working within the .click() function? The alert is displayed correctly, but the page overlay is not.

html

```
<!-- page overlay for login -->
<span id="page-overlay"></span> 

<a href="#" id="clicker">settings</a>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clicker").click(function () {
    alert("Hello!");
    $("#page-overlay").show();
  });
});
```

css

```
#page-overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #E0E0DF;
    opacity: 0.65; 
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/txpg0ysb/2/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jqa468rL/1/ - looks fine - other than the extra `})` in the fiddle...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jqa468rL/2/ - also don't register a handler inside another one as you did, it will add multiple handlers if you click more than once...

Comment: I think its because the span is inline element, while the `.show()` is for inline-block and block elements

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the JQuery version you used in this. Please change `jQuery (edge)` to latest JQuery version (`jQuery 1.10.1`) in your code.